# React Native - Picker doesnt show up in Android only in Web

Tags: react-native, picker

i am currently programming on a Calender. And in the Web i can see the numbers to choose but when i open it up in Android i dont see the numbers anymore. I dont know why it happens but i cant neither see the numbers when i choose them nor when they are choosen in the create appoinment menu.

Here is the Code:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 10 }}>
              {/* Startzeit */}
              <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                <Picker
                  key={selectedStartHour} // Add a key based on the selected value
                  style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
                  selectedValue={selectedStartHour}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedStartHour(itemValue)}
                  itemStyle={{ height: 50 }}
                >
                  {hours.map((hour) => (
                    <Picker.Item
                      key={hour}
                      label={String(hour)}
                      value={String(hour)}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Picker>
              </View>
              <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>:</Text>
              <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                <Picker
                  style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
                  selectedValue={selectedStartMinute}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) =>
                    setSelectedStartMinute(itemValue)
                  }
                  itemStyle={{ height: 50 }}
                >
                  {minutes.map((minute) => (
                    <Picker.Item
                      key={minute}
                      label={String(minute)}
                      value={String(minute)}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Picker>
              </View>
            </View>

            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10 }}>bis</Text>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 10 }}>
              {/* Endzeit */}
              <View style={{ flex: 2, width: "100%" }}>
                <Picker
                  key={selectedStartHour} // Add a key based on the selected value
                  style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}
                  selectedValue={selectedEndHour}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedEndHour(itemValue)}
                  itemStyle={{ height: 50 }}
                >
                  {hours.map((hour) => (
                    <Picker.Item
                      key={hour}
                      label={String(hour)}
                      value={String(hour)}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Picker>
              </View>
              <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>:</Text>
              <View style={{ flex: 2, width: "100%" }}>
                <Picker
                  style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}
                  selectedValue={selectedEndMinute}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedEndMinute(itemValue)}
                  itemStyle={{ height: 50 }}
                >
                  {minutes.map((minute) => (
                    <Picker.Item
                      key={minute}
                      label={String(minute)}
                      value={String(minute)}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Picker>
              </View>
            </View>
```

I used a lot of ChatGTP and also searched a long time through StackOverflow and github for answers.